# Can the primary attribute names be hidden in a custom hero layout?

Tags: dota-2

A friend told me about the "Customize Grid" feature in the hero picker of Dota 2, and about a great website ([Dota2Layout.com](http://www.dota2layout.com/)) to edit those grids. However, that website became incompatible with latest updates to Dota, so for the time being I hacked together [my own DotaGrid editor](http://dotagrid.jeroenheijmans.nl/).

This works just fine, but I can't seem to get rid of the primary attribute names. Here's a screenshot of a custom layout I've created:

[image: custom Dota hero grid with marked offending texts]

**Question:** Is there any way to remove the red-encircled texts ("Strength", "Agility", "Intelligence")?

What I've tried / considered:

- Resetting and exporting the layout, scouring through the file to see if there's anything to tweak;
- Applying some [Google-fu](https://www.google.nl/search?q=dota%20hero%20grid%20remove%20attribute%20names);
- I've checked if dota2layout.com does anything special (by checking exported files);
- Searched the steamapps/dota2 folder for *.jpg or *.png (a long shot, I know).

All to no avail.

Is it currently (6.81b) possible at all to remove those attribute names?

Comment: Upvote, because somehow I never knew you could mess with the hero layout :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something for you! You can change the texts in the `dota_"YourLanguage".txt` file in the resource folder. In case English is the language you use for Dota follow these Steps:

1. Go into the Steam\SteamApps\common\dota 2 beta\dota\resource Folder
2. Open dota_english.txt
3. Press Ctrl + f and search for "DOTA_Hero_Selection"

   Now is the time to remember getting a backup copy of the file.
4. You can change all kinds of stuff here but to simply remove the texts scroll down to:

   ```
   "DOTA_Hero_Selection_Team_Good" "THE RADIANT"
   "DOTA_Hero_Selection_Team_Bad"  "THE DIRE"
   "DOTA_Hero_Selection_STR"       "STRENGTH"
   "DOTA_Hero_Selection_AGI"       "AGILITY"
   "DOTA_Hero_Selection_INT"       "INTELLIGENCE"
   ```

   and change it to:

   ```
   "DOTA_Hero_Selection_Team_Good" "THE RADIANT"
   "DOTA_Hero_Selection_Team_Bad"  "THE DIRE"
   "DOTA_Hero_Selection_STR"       ""
   "DOTA_Hero_Selection_AGI"       ""
   "DOTA_Hero_Selection_INT"       ""
   ```

Awesome work until now! I hope that you can improve your website with this post.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this works as expected. Afraid my little app can't do much with this though, other than provide it as a "quick tip".

Comment: As could be expected though, this file is overwritten usually when Dota updates. Probably not much we can do about that though.